# Filter a list with input type="date" AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

I'm just trying to filter the data from a table on an input type=date with AngularJS. So for example if you select the date 30/04/2016 in the input field I only want to show the records with this date. Fot the moment it is doing nothing, it's not filtering at all. If I change the input type to text the filter works but I want the user to select a date instead of typing a string.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="l">Bidding date</label>
    <input type="date" id="b" ng-model="searchBidding.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission"class="form-control">
</div>
<tbody ng-repeat="result in rowCollection | filter:searchBidding>
    <td >{{result.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>

    <td width="145px"><button type="submit" ng-click="clicked2(result.tenderid)"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <button ng-click="clicked(result.tenderid)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">display</button></td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work or where's the problem?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You understand that `| date:` filter is an output filter, yes?
The filtering logic should be inside `$scope.searchBidding()` function in your controller, right?
So I suppose you should show `searchBidding()` implementation...

Comment: Yeah I know that, but the reason why I use the g-model="searchBidding.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission" and the filter:searchBidding is because Angular automatically knows he has to filter on the {{result.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission}}. There is no function in my controller. This way of working worked for normall strings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to watch for changes in `searchBidding.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission` variable. You can do in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('searchBidding.tenderbiddingdateoffersubmission', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // do whatever ...
    updateFilteredDate();
});
```

Or maybe you could use just [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) (depending on your usecase).

Comment: I think the type="date" makes the problem and not the fact it can't see it has changed

Comment: I don't think `type="data"` is causing the problem, Can you make jsfiddle or plnkr?